# Abaqus/Explicit with user subroutines: ERROR

Tags: abaqus, explicit

When I type abaqus info=system into the abaqus command window, everything looks fine:

**C++ Compiler:         Microsoft Visual C++ 14.29.30147.0
Linker Version:       Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30147.0
Fortran Compiler:     Intel Fortran Compiler 2021.8**

But when I try to run a VUMAT subroutine I get the following error: **Problem during compilation**

When I ran the Abaqus install verification, I get a PASS on most points, but an error on all points involving subroutines. Example:
**Abaqus/Explicit with user subroutines (single precision)**

```
     ...ERROR

        Abaqus did not complete successfully.

        Please see xpl_user.fetch for details.
```

When I open the xpl_user.fetch file, this is what it says:

**Abaqus FETCH job xpl_user.inp
WARNING: The Abaqus installation is incomplete: Example and input files have not been installed.
Please contact your system Administrator for further assistance.**

I have tried to find the problem online, but have not been able to find a solution that has worked.

It is my first time using Abaqus and I would really, really appreciate any suggestions or help! Thank you so much in advance :)